# prefill text field using javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a simple javascript that I can't seem to get to work.

So what I'm trying to accomplish is a text field on my homepage that the user can type in(just 1 field). Submit it and it'll take them to another page with a text field that is pre filled with what they already typed in the first field.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function go_page(page)
{
document.location.href = '/?page_id=11' + '#addressInput=' + addressInput;
}
</script>
```

When i fill in the 'addressInput' (for this example, lets say '90501')..

Currently, the url comes up as www.mywebsite.com/?addressInput=90501

Goal, i want it to be.. www.mywebsite.com/?page_id=11#addressInput=90501

This 'goal url' works when i type it in the address bar. I just need to figure out how to do that function automatically for the user..based on what they input in the first text field.

...any ideas?

**EDIT 1**

Here is the form code..

```
<form method="get" onsubmit=" go_page(this.page.value); return false">
<input type="text" name="addressInput" id="addressInput" size="30" />
<input type="submit" value="" class="submitButton" />
</form>
```

**EDIT 2**

just more info..

The user will be on the homepage and type in an 'address/zip code' in the text field and click submit.

Which will then take them to the locations page(page_id=11) that has a text field that's pre-populated with the 'address/zip' the user typed in on the homepage.

Comment: Are you sure want a # symbol and not a & symbol?

Comment: May I ask why you are using #? Is addressInput another parameter like page_id? If yes, you need & instead of #.

Comment: Doesn't look like a value query string (as noted above). Try using the ampersand instead of the hash symbol

Comment: the # is targeting an textfield with the id addressInput so '90501' is what can be prefilled.

Comment: Is your permalink setting for this WP site using the default?

Comment: @JohnCarter, I believe it is. I dont recall changing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try grabbing the element in the form like this

```
<form method="get" onsubmit="go_page(this.addressInput); return false">
<input type="text" name="addressInput" id="addressInput" size="30" />
<input type="submit" value="" class="submitButton" />
</form>
```

And extracting the value of addressInput inside your function like this

```
function go_page(elem) {
var addressInput = elem.value;
window.location.href = "/?page_id=11#addressInput"+addressInput;
}
```

In Wordpress that should navigate you to the page id and add the hash to the end

Comment: i used your suggestions here and changed the url string to.. window.location.href = "/dealer/?address=" + addressInput;
this worked for what i needed. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have `#` in the URL, you have to encode it so instead of using `#` use `%23`. **And do not forget that for separating values in URL you have to use `&`.**

```
document.location.href = '/?page_id=11' + '%23addressInput=' + addressInput;
```

**Update**

Instead of `document.location.href` use `window.location`

Comment: it's also missing the 'page_id=11'

Comment: @DannyKim : Have you tried what I suggested by updating my answer ?

Comment: just tried it. got the same results. the url keeps coming up with www.mywebsite.com/?addressInput=90501

Comment: would you know how to do this in PHP?

Comment: You can not change URL by PHP in client-side, unless the page being submitted to server and before sending any data from server to browser by using header('Location : example.com');

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear from the limited information provided, but have you stopped the default form submission behavior? Maybe the form if being submitted before your javascript is called. Capture the form submission and `return:false` or `event.preventDefault()` to stop it continuing with the submission.